# How to Timestamp Photo Attachments in ESRI Collector App

Tags: arcgis-collector, timestamp

We need to automatically timestamp the photo attachments when using ESRI Collector APP.  Either a visual timestamp on the photo or a date in the attachment name would be great. Timestamp in the metadata is only partially useful.  Field crews use a variety of devices (iOS, android) so looking for a general solution or unique solutions depending on platform.  We collect a lot of data, so manually changing the photo name is not practical.

Comment: Can you use editor tracking fields as the timestamp?

Comment: Thanks for the idea Russs. I haven't used editor tracking before.  We're interested in the date of each photo attached to a feature.  As I understand, editor tracking will only record the user/date of the LAST edit.